# Stop from terminating program in Ubuntu terminal

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

I've created a program that makes some calculations on random graphs, when I run it on Ubuntu terminal, I've received some initial results from simple graphs but when the graphs get bigger I get "Terminated" from the console as if it took too long to run the program, is that a problem? How to prevent this

Comment: most likely an error in your program. Are you trying to access invalid memory?

Comment: I doubt it's an error as it only happens when terminal has nothing to display for a long time, but who nows

Comment: Check the return code of your program. Since the terminal itself doesn't close down, you could do this. Next, install a signal handler in your program to detect if your program recieve a close signal from an other process. If it doesn't, your program closes itself.

Comment: so, as it turns out bigger graphs use too much ram and swap space, when its full it turns off, changing size of swap space helps, also running program on a computer with more ram is a good idea

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A process can run in the terminal non-stop.

Your process dies because it has no resources to run with. You can solve this by increasing your swap area (your process will be much slower when using the swap) or by increasing your RAM.